# BDD Cucumber Scala Tests in HDFS Cluster

Tags: java, scala, bdd

To give a context; I am trying to do a small POC to bring in BDD approach for testing of a batch application. The whole application involves reading of data from HDFS Clusters.

Till now I have been writing spark scala code and using spark-submit, I use to run it in clusters and get the data and validate it. Now I am attempting to formalize it with a BDD approach. Catch is that I need the scenarios to be executed in the cluster. Could anyone please help? I feel this is feasible but need to know if i am just hitting a rock.

I have attempted to run the feature scenarios using both Scala and Java Runner files.

1. When I am attempting to run the runner file in Cluster using Scala,  I am getting the below error:
   ERROR SparkSubmit: The main method in the given main class must be static
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The main method in the given main class must be static
2. When I am attempting to run the runner file in Cluster using Java,  It is not executing any of my scenarios.

Please find the snippets of the runner files.

Scala Runner File:

```
  import io.cucumber.junit.{Cucumber, CucumberOptions} 
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
    
@RunWith(classOf[Cucumber]) 
@CucumberOptions( features = Array("classpath:features/test_trial1.feature"), glue = Array("classpath:com.sample.steps"), plugin = Array("pretty", "html:target/cucumber/html")) 
class testScalaRunner
```

Java Runner File:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"progress",
                "html:build/report/html",
                "junit:build/report/junit/cucumber-report.xml",
                "json:build/report/json/cucumber-report.json"
        },
        glue = {"classpath:com.sample.steps"},
        features = {"src/main/resources/features"}
)
public class runJavaRunner {

        public static void main(String[] args){
                System.out.println("Inside runJavaRunner Main Method");
                
        }
}
```

spark-submit being used:

```
spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue orchestra1 --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 6g -class com.sample.runner.testScalaRunner cucumber_scala_tests.jar
```

Comment: Spark-submit requires the main function to create a spark context for the application. You cannot ask spark-submit to run the cucumber tests. Instead instantiate a SparkContext first, then run the cucumber tests using that context (pass it to the tests).

Comment: I have created a trait to initiate a sparkSession and extended this trait in my runner file. Do you mean this? How to run the cucumber tests using the sparkContext?

Comment: That should work. The context is to just get a spark connection to any server (it could also be a context to local, which is generally what is done for tests). Also note that in newer versions of spark, the context is replaced with spark session, which is a singleton, to get the connection.

You then just run the cucumber test as you would regularly and create test dataframes at runtime to use for any of your spark transformations.

There is also a scala-cucumber library that you can use and has all the traits and runners for use with scala.

Comment: I have added all the cucumber scala dependencies. I have the runner object extending the sparkSession trait.

Comment: package com.sample.runner

import com.sample.util.launchSparkSession
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

object testScalaRunner extends launchSparkSession{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  var glue = "com.sample.steps"
  val fileNames = "hdfs:///cucumber_features/src/main/resources/features/test_trial1.feature"
  fileNames.foreach(x => spark.sparkContext.addFile(fileNames))
  Main.main(glue,SparkFiles.get("test_trial1.feature"))

  }

}

Comment: This is the runner file. I am not sure how to proceed anymore..I have created a fat jar and then deployed the jar to the cluster. Trying to execute the runner file using spark submit. Not sure if i have to add any more jars to support the spark submit. Any help would be great

Comment: Since you're running your test, why not just run it locally? You would use `sbt test`  or `sbt clean install` for that. It's similar to `mvn test`. This is usually how you run the test. You don't run it as a spark-submit job. If you need to test with data on the cluster, try and get a sample of it and run it against your test locally.

Comment: Unit tests are doing that..I am writing acceptance tests so that business coordination can also happen smoothly. Also I need my tests to run in cluster. So I am having to rely on spark-submit

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if this can be triggered this way and on a cluster. The spark-submit finds the main function and runs it (that is provided as an argument). And cucumber does that as well, so there may be some conflict there. Or the spark submit is not able to understand the cucumber annotations.